# jQueryUI Autocomplete Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to implement something like autocomplete feature like this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

However I cannot do that. Here is my code:

```
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/JScript-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jQueryUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
     $('[id$="tbSearch"]').autocomplete({
         source: availableTags
     });
 });
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Nothing is showing as a dropdown in my textbox: tbSearch. What is going wrong here?

Comment: @Marek: No. tbSearch is a TextBox which has runat = "server" property.

Comment: @klm9971... have you actually imported jQuery? `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/source/jQuery.js"></script>`

Comment: @Hristo: Please chk my latest edit in the question.

Comment: First off, why do you have **both** `jquery-1.4.1-min.js` and `jquery-1.4.1.js` imported? You only need one. :D

Comment: LOL, I thought why the F my code is not working...

Comment: Well, removing one won't fix it, definitely. This is more of a performance (redundancy) thing. :D

Comment: Yea, I removed it. Check my latest edits in my question. This time also it is not populating availbleTags.

Comment: Are you sure that you've imported jQuery and the autocomplete jQueryUI plugin correctly? Because your code seems to be working just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/WPuLc/1/

Comment: jQuery has the recent version of 1.5.1. How you import the jQueryUI plugin?

Comment: This is the third time you've posted this question in a 24-hour period.  You would probably get better results if you only posted once, and commented on that one post.

Comment: Yeah, and still you're using jQuery 1.4.1. And autocomplete is part of jQueryUI. You import jQueryUI just as you would import any other JS file.

Comment: @Rich: Made the changes you said. See the updated code. It is still not firing up. I think something is wrong on my side :(

Comment: dude, no offense, but the more we talk about what you're doing, the more I'm convinced that you really don't know what you're working with. you'll have to understand what jQuery and jQueryUI are first, then add them into your page, then that's when you can use the `.autocomplete()` function from jQueryUI. At this point, I'm not even sure if you actually have both JS files in your web site.

Comment: Okay, Rich. My bad. I need to brush up my skills again...

Comment: re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5475290/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Alright! Thank you Will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in ASP.NET the ID of the control is used when referring to it in the code file or code behind, and isn't the actual ID of the input field when rendered to HTML.  View the source of your page to see the actual ID.  You probably want something like this:

```
$("#<%= tbSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
...
```

or

```
$("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
...

<asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server" CssClass="autocomplete"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What this ClientID mean? I dont have any such parameter in my code.

Comment: ClientID is the actual Id that the DOM element has when the control is rendered to the page.  Try viewing the source of your page - you might notice that the IDs that you're giving the WebControls and UserControls don't necessarily match up with what is actually found in the page - for example, the ID for your text box above might actually render to something like "ctl100_Content_tbSearch".  See this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: Okay! Thanks Rich. I made changes to my code above. Pls chk it.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. Your code comes *before* the HTML it wants to affect.
2. Even if you fix (1), you'll have the problem that the *actual* client-side "id" value will not be the value you coded into your ASP tag.  You have to call some ASP thing to get the client-side value.

oh wait: also, it's ".click", not ".Click".

It would also be an extremely good idea to use the `var` keyword where you declare/define the "data" variable in the "success" handler.

*edit* — notice that in the example to which your question linked, the jQuery setup code is inside a jQuery "ready" handler.  That will ensure that problem 1 is fixed.  I'm not sure why you're wiring a "click" handler up to a "text box" element; if that generates an `<input type="text">` tag then you won't get any clicks from that anyway (I don't think) (*edit* that's wrong); even if you did, it's kind-of weird.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I am basically using Master Page to my Testing Page. So where should I put my code? In the testing.aspx.

Comment: I'm not an ASP programmer so I'm not exactly sure how to deal with the "id" issue; I know it's a really simple thing to do however and it's in Stackoverflow answers here and there.  The sample code you linked to shows how to use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` for initialization code.

Comment: Yes, but: you're still trying to attach the "click" handler to the "tbSearch" element, and you're trying to put the results in an element called "ya" that doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see here is that you're referencing ID "tbSearch" as follows:

```
$("#tbSearch").autocomplete(data);
```

Yet once the .NET framework renders this page, the client ID of the textbox will be much different.  You can use the following instead to make sure the ID you're referencing in your jQuery code is correct:

```
$('#<%= tbSearch.ClientID %>').autocomplete(data);
```

A couple of things you can do to debug right off the bat:

1. Add an error handler to your jquery .ajax call.

   ```
       error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(errorThrown);
       }
   ```
2. Set a breakpoint in your web method.  Are you hitting it?

Comment: I am calling this JQ as soon my page loads.

Comment: In your success handler, you are receiving the return value in parameter "data", yet you are overwriting this value with `msg.d.split.split(" ")`.  This should be causing a javascript error.  I assume you want to split (on space char) the value passed via the data param.

Comment: Yes! But I am not getting any error when I trying to run the page :(

Comment: Nops! I am not hitting my WebMethod. I think because I am writing tbSearch.Click funtion. However, I want to do just like dynamic auto-complete feature.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention you have the same problem on the line `$("#tbSearch").click(function () {` - should be `$('#<%= tbSearch.ClientID %>').click(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

As Keith pointed out, you are overwriting the response that you are getting from the server:

```
success: function (data) {                    
   data = msg.d.split(" ");             
   $('#<%= tbSearch.ClientID %>').autocomplete(data);                 
}
```

Perhaps what you are trying to do is:

```
data = data.split(" ");
```

When you click your text box, and the Click() event is fired, all you are doing is providing the Data for the autocomplete. You aren't actually invoking the drop down. To do that, you need to call the search method. Also, keep in mind that there is a minLength property which can prevent the drop-down from opening:

```
//Set the minLength to zero
$("#tbSearch").autocomplete("minLength", 0");
//Now invoke the search   
$("#tbSearch").autocomplete("search", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request you are posting no data.

Assuming you are using this plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

try using

```
$("#tbSearch").autocomplete("AgentList.aspx/LoadData");
```

and returning an array in your web service

Comment: I edited my question above. What you have suggested, it is still not firing up. Yes you are right, I am following up this link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but it looks like you're using the autocomplete plugin incorrectly. You are attaching to the change event on a textbox, and based on the name of that textbox I'm assuming you're looking to use autocomplete for search suggestions based on what the user inputs.

If that is the case, then you simply need to attach the autocomplete functionality to the textbox in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tbSearch").autocomplete("AgentList.aspx/LoadData");
});
```

The plugin will take care of the AJAX request — you don't have to.

Comment: I did this, but I am not getting anything from UI.

Answer (score 0):

Your `asp:TextBox`, while having an ID set to "tbSearch", will not be exactly that when it goes to your browser. ASP.NET adds a bit to your ID that helps it identify your control server-side.

Try this instead:

```
$('[id$="tbSearch"]').autocomplete({
    source : availableTags
});
```

Comment: I made amendments to my question. Please review it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fully functioning example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function() {        
         var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $('#tbSearch').autocomplete(availableTags);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id = "tbSearch" name="code">
  </body>
</html>
```